# How to change text of OS X menu bar with the app name

Tags: macos, nsmenu

I have an app with a target/bundle name `MyApp`. For all the OS X App there are a menu bar that has the app name. Can you change the text of that menu bar without changing the bundle name. I saw some apps does that.